# Accessing ng-content from component code without a wrapper ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

Let's say I have a component called RecursiveComponent (with a selector named recursive). It has a number "identifier" as input, as well as accepting more RecursiveComponents in its body. So the HTML code that uses this component may look like this:

```
<recursive identifier="1">
  <recursive identifier="2">
    <recursive identifier="3"></recursive>
  </recursive>
  <recursive identifier="4"></recursive>
</recursive>
```

For simplicity, the component only outputs "*identifier* has *x* children" and then the inserted body which is done through `<ng-content>`. This works, but to figure out how many children components there are, I have to wrap the ng-content with a ViewChild and look at the nativeElement's childNodes, which I feel is a little overkill. This is what the component code looks like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'recursive',
  template: `
    {{identifier}} has {{noOfChildren}} children 
    <div #contentRef>
      <ng-content select="recursive"></ng-content>
    </div>`
})
export class RecursiveComponent implements OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('contentRef', { read: ElementRef }) contentRef: ElementRef;

  @Input() identifier: number;

  noOfChildren: number;

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.contentRef) {
      this.noOfChildren = this.contentRef.nativeElement.childNodes.length;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better and more Angular-like way to access the ng-content from within the component code? This feels like a hack.

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wz8zu6

Comment: when the question is better than the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably the only way you can do something like this, you need access to the elements in the DOM. There is however another (Possibly better) way of doing this with @ViewChildren.

> You can use ViewChildren to get the QueryList of elements or
>   directives from the view DOM. Any time a child element is added,
>   removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes
>   observable of the query list will emit a new value.

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#viewchildren

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look into that. What I was thinking was something like a variable that contains the inner content that I can access through some kind of init method without the need of a templateReference. Kind of like the transclude function that you could get through the link method in AngularJS. But I guess this is OK

Comment: Yes you could do something like that, but it would probably end up being a more expensive operation. Would you mind accepting my answer please, would be much appreciated.